# Does Mortal Kombat 9: Komplete Edition have the 4 extra characters on the disk? or do we need to download them?

Tags: ps3, mortal-kombat-9, mortal-kombat-komplete-edition

Can someone tell me if the komplete edition has the 4 extra characters on the disc or we should download them on internet?

I'm on a PS3

[image: Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition]

Comment: I would say that you have to download them - but I can't be certain, I've never played the game

Answer (score 1):

It Contains The Characters as Part Of The Komplet Edition , see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_(2011_video_game)#Komplete_Edition